# Unable to delete file" blah...mule-plugin-debugger\lib\xstream-1.4.10.jar

Tags: java, mule, anypoint-studio

has anyone seen this error below in Mulesoft (Anypoint Studio 6.4.3). It only happens when I try to debug or run Munit. I have been banging my head against the wall for 2 days.. No luck.. Any help is appreciated.

```
INFO  2018-02-13 14:00:15,982 [main] 
com.cox.automotive.edi9.service.util.EDI9Config: java.io.tmpdir => 
C:\WINDOWS\
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: 
C:\Users\roca\AnypointStudio\temp\1040065550572595\mule-plugin-
debugger\lib\xstream-1.4.10.jar
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2279)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1653)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1535)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2270)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1653)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1535)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2270)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1653)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1535)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2270)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1653)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1535)
at org.mule.munit.plugins.coverage.extensions.MunitPluginCoreExtension.deleteWinTempDirectory(MunitPluginCoreExtension.java:218)
at org.mule.munit.plugins.coverage.extensions.MunitPluginCoreExtension.createWinTempDirectory(MunitPluginCoreExtension.java:223)
at org.mule.munit.plugins.coverage.extensions.MunitPluginCoreExtension.createTempDirectory(MunitPluginCoreExtension.java:182)
at org.mule.munit.plugins.coverage.extensions.MunitPluginCoreExtension.createDebuggerPluginTempFolder(MunitPluginCoreExtension.java:166)
at org.mule.munit.plugins.coverage.extensions.MunitPluginCoreExtension.createDefaultPluginManager(MunitPluginCoreExtension.java:93)
at org.mule.munit.plugins.coverage.extensions.MunitPluginCoreExtension.initialise(MunitPluginCoreExtension.java:64)
at org.mule.module.launcher.coreextension.DefaultMuleCoreExtensionManager.initializeCoreExtensions(DefaultMuleCoreExtensionManager.java:142)
at org.mule.module.launcher.coreextension.DefaultMuleCoreExtensionManager.initialise(DefaultMuleCoreExtensionManager.java:74)
at org.mule.munit.plugins.coverage.extensions.MunitMuleExtensionsLoaderPlugin.initialise(MunitMuleExtensionsLoaderPlugin.java:44)
at org.mule.munit.runner.MuleContextManager.initialisePlugins(MuleContextManager.java:224)
at org.mule.munit.runner.MuleContextManager.createMule(MuleContextManager.java:126)
at org.mule.munit.runner.MuleContextManager.startMule(MuleContextManager.java:70)
at org.mule.munit.runner.mule.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:53)
at org.mule.munit.runner.mule.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:45)
at org.mule.munit.remote.RemoteRunner.runTestSuite(RemoteRunner.java:75)
at org.mule.munit.remote.RemoteRunner.run(RemoteRunner.java:55)
at org.mule.munit.remote.RemoteRunner.main(RemoteRunner.java:39)
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable Munit coverage `<runCoverage>false</runCoverage>` if you dont need.

Also always "run as administrator" if windows.